# Where is custom template file chosen for a post stored in the DB?

Tags: database, admin

Where is the custom template file that has been selected through the wordpress edit screen (for a post or page) stored in the wordpress database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the post meta table (usually `wp_postmeta`), with the page id in post_id, meta_key with `_wp_page_template` and meta_value with the template file name.

Answer (score 0):

Example select query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
# AND post_id = 50
```

Example update query:

```sql
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 'templates/template-example.php'
WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
  AND post_id = 50;
```